# Не работают ссылки на сетевые папки пересланные через Thunderbird

Tags: ссылка, thunderbird

Cсылки на ЛОКАЛЬНЫЕ папки на латинице - открываются(но после ассоциирования их с Explorer.exe через параметр file:\)

ссылки на кирилические локальные папки - не работают(Если открыть исходный код письма то кириллица крашится), перепробовал всевозможные варианты кодировки, может что-то упустил.

Ссылки на сетевые папки нашей организации на латинице через параметр file:\ - ведут исключительно в папку Мои документы на локальный диск С
Ссылки на сетевые папки на латинице  - не открываются никак.

Примечательно, что любой ресурс нашей организации скопированный из адресной строки и вставленный в Chrome - открывается без проблем, но обратная операция не работает, т.е. копируя из адресной строки хрома ссылку с символами типа - %,  я получаю результат прошлых вариантов.

Comment: Приведите примеры проблемных ссылок.

Comment: \\MTO-main\Common\Scan  - ссылка на сетевую папку, открывается через file:/, но попадаешь не в вышеуказанную папку, а в C:\Users\User\Documents                              
 \\MTO-main\Common\Scan\Кириллица\ - ссылка на сетевую папку такого вида даже неактивна

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что почтовик пытается открыть ссылку в папке того пользователя, в контексте, которого он работает. Но, это и не удивительно. Ведь задача почтовика отправлять и получать письма, а не решать вопросы системного  администрирования. Да и встроенную политику безопасности никто не отменял.

Comment: Ссылка в тексте сообщения естественно неактивна, т.к. это не интернетовская ссылка и потому она не может быть опознана программой как ссылка.

Comment: Попробуйте пересылать файлы ярлыков на сетевые ресурсы. Может прокатит.

Comment: 1.не прокатило 2. С чего вы взяли что ссылка естественно не активна, после  ассоциирования с Explorer она активна и даже кликабельна, только никуда не ведёт! 3. Задача примитивного почтовика, может быть и заключается только лишь в отправке писем, но птица таковым не является, по крайней мере они себя так позиционируют.В Аутлуке это реализовано очень просто, а тут танцы..

Comment: Ключевые слова "после ассоциирования". Если в Outlook работает, то почему бы не использовать его? Или не настроить рабочий стол сразу через AD или ещё как-то?